# Two windows at a time?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to activate a pi camera attached to a raspberry module using python. here is my sample code. ON running this code i am getting two windows showing the video. When i tried for processing the video, i get a window of a processed video and one real video. i am jst trying to get a single window. can anyone suggest why is it happening.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
ret,th = cap.read()
cv2.imshow('video',th)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You're not doing any processing here; what do you mean processed video and real video? Is there a separate code you're running? And, I'm not sure, does the RaspiCam even show up as `/dev/video0`?

Comment: This is just a part of code. Even if i run this code... i am getting two windows showing same video.

Comment: Search for any other imshow in your code an change it's string to "video" or remove that imshow.

Comment: only one imshow is there. One window corresponds to picamera and the other corresponds to webcam cv2.VideoCapture(0). I just need the picamera and want to process the video in picamera. But whatever processing am doing is happening in webcam window.

Comment: try changing `cv2.imshow('video',th)` to `cv2.imshow('picamera',th)` or whatever that window is labeled.